# I'm getting same multiple Sqs message before visibility timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I set visibility time out 12 hours and max message 3, delay time 15 min, I'm get sqs message few minute after automatically I get same message again.

Why do I get multiple sqs message without timeout?
After visibility time out it delete message in queue or send again sqs message?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When `ReceiveMessage()` is called on an Amazon SQS queue, up to 10 messages (configurable) will be retrieved from the queue.

These messages will be marked as **Invisible** or **In-Flight**. This means that the messages are still in the queue, but will not be returned via another `ReceiveMessage()` call. The messages will **remain invisible for a period of time**. The default period is configured on the queue ("Default Visibility Timeout") or when the messages are retrieved (`VisibilityTimeout`).

When an application has finished handling a message, it should call `DeleteMessage()`, passing the `MessageHandle` that was provided with the message. The message will then be **deleted from the queue**.

If the invisibility period expires before a message is deleted, it will be **placed on the queue again** and applications can retrieve it again. Therefore, be sure to set your invisibility timeout to be longer than an application normally takes to process a message.

It is *possible* that a message may be **retrieved more than once** from Amazon SQS. It is rare, but can happen where there are multiple processes retrieving messages simultaneously. Thus, SQS is "At least once delivery". If this is a problem, you can use **FIFO Queues** (not yet available in every region) that will guarantee that each message is delivered only once, but there are throughput restrictions on FIFO queues.

So, if you are receiving a message more than once:

- You should **check your invisibility timeout** setting (both the default setting and the value that can be passed when you call `ReceiveMessage()`)
- Consider using **FIFO queues**
- Have your application check whether a message has already been processed before processing it again (eg via a **unique ID**)

Comment: What is invisibility time out  ,I didn't see these options in AWS , I have another question is how I received same message again and again it happen. Before visibility timeout

Comment: My reference to *invisibility timeout* is the same as *visibility timeout* (sorry for the inconsistent wording). It is shown in the console as **Default Visibility Timeout** and in code as `VisibilityTimeout`. My whole answer is related to your receiving the same message repeatedly, and ways you could try to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed Explanation

Comment: Is there anything in the message by SQS that is deemed unique across multiple deliveries so it can be used as that unique ID? MessageId? Signature? Or you should generate one yourself?

Comment: @jbernal Please ask a new Question rather than asking in a comment on an old question. Also, see **Receipt Handle** on [Queue and Message Identifiers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-queue-message-identifiers.html).